# Как безопасно передать данные от сервера клиенту?

Tags: java, android

Всем добрый день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: я создал Android приложение, которое будет получать данные из интернета. Сначала думал организовать парсинг из JSON, который лежит на сайте, но подумав понял, что будут передаваться конфеденциальные данные, а к json файлу может получить доступ любой, кто знает адрес. Так вот вопрос: как безопасно передать данные от сервера клиенту(Android приложению)?

Comment: ssl + токен авторизации.

Answer (score 1):

Логично обеспечить end-to-end шифрование. Посмотрите в сторону openSSL, wolfSSL или более специализированных под android библиотек шифрования. Обычно используется связка из обмена ключами RSA и блочным шифрованием AES 128. Конечно, можете использовать и ГОСТ шифрования, например ГОСТ 28147-89, но это сложней реализовать и почти необоснованно. Конечно, если вы не собрались проходить аттестацию приложения гос. структурами. Универсальный совет, ищите готовые реализации, они существуют в изобилии.

P.S. Не силён в специфике андроид разработки.

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать шифрованный websocket - wss. для начала требуется определиться с уровнем защиты, как правило от терморектального взлома защиты нет.